# How to pass input arguments to a parent class during instantiation without passing them through the child's init method in Python?

Tags: python, inheritance, interface

If I provide an interface class via my library

```py
class Task:
    def __init__(self, additional_arg1 = None, additional_arg2  = None):
        # register args
        self.additional_arg1 = additional_arg1
        self.additional_arg2 = additional_arg2
```

and a user inherits from it

```py
class MyTask(Task):
    def __init__(self, *user_args, **user_kwargs):
        super().__init__()
        # register user args
        ...
```

is there a way for me to instantiate `MyTask` within the library so that the additional task arguments
are provided and registered to the `Task.__init__` method without going through the `MyTask.__init__` method?

Currently I do sth like this

```py
# this happens inside my package (the user provided his MyTask and his input args, 
# and I dynamically add the additional args that are registered in the Task interface

task = MyTask(*user_args, **user_kwargs)
task.additional_arg1 = additional_arg1
task.additional_arg2 = additional_arg2
```

The issue here is, that the user has no access to `additional_arg1` within the `MyTask.__init__` method that he defines.

Is there a way to achieve this without passing the additional args through the `MyTask.__init__` and the `super` method?
I would like the user not being exposed to these additional args in his class setup.
However, he should have the option to access these attributes anyways.
Is that even possible with instance attributes?

Can I somehow init the interface/parent class and make its attributes accessible in the user defined `MyTask.__init__` without
the user needing to implement anything specific (like alter the function signature and passing arguments to super) in `MyTask.__init__`?

Thanks for your suggestions.

**Update (in response to comments):**

I don't want that the user is forced to add the additional task arguments to the function signature of `MyTask.__init__`.
The proposed solution of `MyTask(**(user_kwargs | mandatory_kwargs))` would require a `MyTask` implementation by the user like:

```py
class MyTask(Task):
   def __init__(self, *user_args, *additional_args, **user_kwargs, **additional_kwargs):
       super().__init__(*additional_args, **additional_kwargs)
       # register user args
       ...
```

which I try to avoid.

The problem with my current setup is that there are cases, where the user wants to access an additional attribute from within `MyTask.__init__`, e.g.

```py
class MyTask(Task):
    def __init__(self, *user_args, **user_kwargs):
        super().__init__()
        # register user args
        ...
        # do sth with additional_arg1
        # however, at this point the attribute is not set yet as it is only set dynamically after initialization (see above), so here it would still be None
        print(self.additional_arg1)
```

So is there a way to make the above work? Somehow I would like to register the additional args externally so that they are already available during the `MyTask.__init__` method.

**Update 2:**

Maybe my lengthy explanation above was not clear enough. I found a solution for what I want using `globals`, but I would prefer getting around them.
This is the how the solution looks like:

```py
from typing import Dict


A = None
B = None


def set_args(a, b):
    global A
    global B
    A = a
    B = b


class Task:
    """Base task implemented in package"""

    def __init__(self):
        self.a = A  # set additional attributes from globals
        self.b = B

    @classmethod
    def from_cfg(cls, task_class: type, cfg: Dict):
        set_args(a=5, b=6)  # register additional args as globals
        return task_class(**cfg)  # instantiate my_task instance and retrieve globals to dynamically register additional args


class MyTask(Task):
    """This task is implemented by the user
    The additional attributes a and b should be available from the init without the need to specifically provide them to the __init__ as input args.
    """

    def __init__(self, c, d):
        super().__init__()
        self.c = c
        self.d = d
        
        print(self.a)  # This works now and prints 5 instead of None

    def run(self):
        pass


def main():

    my_task = Task.from_cfg(MyTask, {"c": 1, "d": 2})
    print(my_task.a)  # prints 5 again


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The `my_task` instance is created from the classmethod `from_cfg`. Within this method I want to register the additional arguments `a` and `b` so that they are available within the `MyTask__init__` without passing them through as normal arguments. If there is a neat way to achieve the above without globals, let me know :)

Comment: can't you do something like `MyTask(**(user_kwargs | mandatory_kwargs))`?

Comment: I don't see what is wrong with what you have. Maybe just wrap the code into a function which requires all the necessary parameters.

Comment: I added some additional information (see update), in response to your suggestions.

Comment: Call a function to set the attributes.

Comment: @quamrana I don't really get how setting the attributes with a function resolves the issue. Maybe I'm missing sth. Do you have an example?

Comment: Where are the values for these attribute going to be generated? The `__init__()` seems to know that these attributes are needed, so it should call a function to get them.

Comment: @quamrana The additional attribute values are generated outside/before the task instantiation. I look for a way that they are registered in the parent `__init__()` so that the user can simply access them within the child `__init__()` without passing them through the function signature. I was hoping for some black magic I'm not aware off... 

Which `__init__()` are you refering to? How can a function within the `Task.__init__()` dynamically retrieve the attributes? Since they are not provided as input to `Task.__init__()` they're not in the same scope.

Comment: My question was *where* are the values generated. You answered with *when*. Define a function near where the values are generated. Call that function within `MyTask.__init__()`

Comment: The additional attributes should be registered from a `@classmethod` of the `Task` class before actually instantiated `MyTask` and subsequently `Task` via inheritance. Defining a function at that point and calling it from within `Task.__init__` (I don't want to call it from `MyTask.__init__` since this is in the control of the user) to register the attributes is not possible since the function is not in the scope of `Task.__init__`. I found a solution using `globals` but it is not so nice. However, it might be the only way...